# xml parsing node value

Tags: xml-parsing

I have an xml file to upload in sql

the xml is like

```
 <catalog>
  <products>
  <product>
  <ID>0079</ID>
  <NAME>Casa</NAME>
  <feature name="material">cemento</feature>
  </product>
  </products>
  </catalog>
```

I do:

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file('prova.xml');
  $listProducts = $xml->products;
  foreach ($listProducts->product as $product)
  { 
   $name           = $product->NAME;
   $id= $product->ID;
    ....................
```

But the prodblem is when I must define the variable "FEATURE"

I want insert in my sql the value "CEMENTO"

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if it works

```
$feature = $product->feature;
$featureName = $product->feature->attributes()->name;
```

UPDATE

```
foreach ($listProducts->product as $product)
{ 
    $name = $product->NAME;
    $id= $product->ID;

    foreach ($product->feature as $feature)
    { 
        $featureName = $feature->attributes()->name;
    }
```

...

Comment: hI MARCO 
if I use
     $feature = $product->feature;
it give me the value cemento

the problem is that i have a lot of feature with different name

For ex:

      <feature name="agenzia">tecnocasa</feature>
      <feature name="venditore">Privato</feature>

etc...

if I use only $featureName = $product->feature->attributes()->name
it give me the value PRODUTTORE that I don't want

Comment: I see you have more than one feature, so use the same as you did before, create a foreach over all features.

Comment: ok Marco thanks...but sorry if I done this it give me in the sql MAterial...perhaps I must done an if?
 so
foreach ($listProducts->product as $product)
{ 
    $name = $product->NAME;
    $id= $product->ID;

    foreach ($product->feature as $feature)
    { 
        $featureName = $feature->attributes()->name;
        if ($featureName='PRODUTTORE'){
 $material= $product->feature}
    }

IS IT?

Comment: where is PRODUTTORE in the xml? Can you update the xml in you example with PRODUTTORE?

Comment: By the way if you want to compare something use == not just one =